# What is the recommended way to enable the installation of Rmpi across platforms in a Makefile?

Tags: r, linux, macos, makefile

To enable easy reproducibility of results, my team and I have been using Makefiles to organize our R+latex based workflow. One problem we've discovered is that Rmpi requires different configuration arguments on different systems. For example, on a recent OS X with openmpi installed by `brew install openmpi` a simple `install.packages('Rmpi')` does not work. I'm posting my current solution here but am wondering if there is a better way --- right now, a user will have to know the correct configure arguments for their particular machine and hand edit the Makefile. Here, for example, `keeling`, is a linux cluster at the University of Illinois, otherwise we assume users have our same OS X+homebrew setup. I'd like to make this more automatic and flexible.

Lines from the makefile follow.

```
HOST=$(shell hostname)

paper.pdf: [dependencies including .libraries/Rmpi/INSTALLED]

.libraries/Rmpi/INSTALLED:
    mkdir -p libraries
ifeq ($(findstring keeling,$(HOST)),keeling)
    R_COMPILE_PKGS=1 R_LIBS=libraries R --vanilla -e "install.packages('Rmpi', type='source', repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/',dependencies=TRUE,configure.args=c('--with-mpi=/sw/openmpi-1.6.4a-intel-14.0.3 --with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI'))"
    date > libraries/Rmpi/INSTALLED
      else
    R_COMPILE_PKGS=1 R_LIBS=libraries R --vanilla -e "install.packages('Rmpi',type='source',repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/',dependencies=TRUE,configure.args=c('--with-Rmpi-include=/usr/local/include --with-Rmpi-libpath=/usr/local/lib --with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI'))
    date > libraries/Rmpi/INSTALLED
endif
```

Comment: `I'd like to make this more automatic and flexible.` - `Make` utility is intended for **build** project, but it has very limited support for **configure** project, that is adjusting its properties for specific machine and user's needs. You may use `CMake` or other tools suitable for *configuration*.

Comment: If you know which parts of those commands do and don't need modifying you could split them into make variables and then people could just override those at `make` run time.That said I generally agree with @Tsyvarev that make isn't necessarily the best suited tool for this and that any of the current suite of configuration management tools (which does **not** in any way include cmake as far as I know) might be a better fit.